# Equivalent of a Equation

Tags: real-analysis

> $$E_{1} : \sqrt[3]{1+z}-\sqrt[3]{1-z}=\sqrt[6]{1-z^{2}} $$
>
> Let $a=\sqrt[3]{1+z}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{1-z}$
>
> $E_1$ is equivalent to $E_2$ :
>
> $$ E_2:\   \dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}-\dfrac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}=1$$

Let $t=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$, show that t verify :

$$  E_{3}:\ t^2-t-1  $$

The original :
[image]

I think it's easy to show it but i'm not sure if answer it's good one

we've $t=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ then $E_2$ become

$$t-\dfrac{1}{t}=1 \text{ since } t\geq 0  $$
\begin{align}
t^{2}-1&=t\\
t^{2}-t-1&=0
\end{align}

Am i right ?

Comment: Your argument looks good, except you don't need to mention $t\geq 0$. What is needed is that $a>0$ and $b>0$ so that the fractions and the square roots make sense.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}-\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}=1\\\frac{(\sqrt{a})^2-(\sqrt{b})^2}{\sqrt{ab}}=1\\a-b=\sqrt{ab}\\now-put-a,b-here\\a=\sqrt[3]{1+z} ,b=\sqrt[3]{1-z}\\so\\\sqrt[3]{1+z}+\sqrt[3]{1-z}=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{1+z}\sqrt[3]{1-z}}=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{1-z^2}}=\sqrt[6]{1-z^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks sir but this not my question i want to show that if $t=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ then $t$ verify $E_{3}:t^{2}-t-1=0$